# IIS 7 can't connect to SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, connection-string

Sorry if this is the most seen question on the web, but this is my turn. I am trying to publish my asp.net mvc app on IIS 7 under MS Sql Server 2008. I am on a Windows Server 2008 virtual machine. I get the following classical error:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

Under SQLServer, Allow remote connections is checked. My connection string is:

Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=mydbname;User Id=sa;Password=mypassword

I also tried with no username/password and "Integrated Security=true". There is only one instance of SQLServer installed.
I tried to access my web page locally and remotely. There is no active firewall on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks guys for the try. I found the solution and it is related to an info that I forgot to give. I hope it can help someone as new as me on these things.

I use NHibernate, and the connection string is actually in the nhibernate.cfg.xml file. The one in the web.config file is actually used by my various providers (users/roles). I fixed that by removing the connection string from the NH config file. I now retrieve it with:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["myConnectString"].ConnectionString;
```

and I set it in NH with:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure(cfgFile);
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, connectionString);
```

Now I get:

> Cannot open database "mydb"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

But this is another story, for another question if I can't find the answer.

PS: I had to use "." as the server name otherwise .\MSSQLSERVER was producing a new error "invalid connection string". Thx Ian and Jared for the tip.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted.

Comment: About the "login failed" - Are you running a non-english Operation System?

For some reasons, the account name of "NT Authority\Network Service" has been localized in other languages.  
Sadly, a lot of programs have the account name hard coded to the english name, and won't find the Network Service when running on foreign versions of Windows.

Comment: Thx Sam, but no it was not that. Just an issue with permission.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have TCP/IP set up as a transport in your SQL Server configuration tool.

Comment: In the transports for MSSQLSERVER I can see that tcpip is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

is that the actual data source line from the web config?

If so then it's should be in quotes of course, for safety add a ; on the end and check that is the actual name of your instance,  you can check windows services for your instance name.

try substituting `localhost` instead of `.` and can you connect from sql server management studio using the credentials in your connection string?

Comment: Yes this is the line from my web config file. It's with quotes and actually there is already ";" at the end. I use these credentials inside management studio with success. Substituting by localhost doesn't work either. And yes MSSQLSERVER is the instance name (checked under services)

Comment: Basically we are all thinking this should be simple and it should be working :).  Sorry the simple stuff didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Robert, try:

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=(LOCAL)\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=mydbname;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword"
```

I'm not sure if connection strings are case sensitve, but I notice that you have 'Id' instead of 'ID'.

Edit:
Am not sure if you need \MSSQLSERVER?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure it's a named instance of SQL?

try

Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydbname;User Id=sa;Password=mypassword

UPDATE:

from [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx)

did you try the following:

- Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
- Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.
- If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.

Comment: Thx Jared, I also did the checklist you mention. No success.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am facing the same above issue since morning (past 8 hours) did lots of stuff like create a Domain Name, setup a new application pool identity but nothing worked :(

I just made a small changes in `web.config` file for connection string that is:

Integrated Security=False instead of True... and now it is working perfectly

Comment: basically Integrated Security =True means --- the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication. so Make it False when your connection is using SQL Server authentication instead of Windows